# ActivationData only passed when model is explicitly set in Durandal

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, composition

I have been messing with Durandal 2.1.0 for the first time and noticed something strange that I don't understand.

I have an observable called **composedView** that is bound to a select control on my page. I have loaded the select up with two values, 'compositionTest1' and 'compositionTest2'.

On another part of the page I have a div element with the compose binding on it and I have set the activationData property of the binding to 'Here'.

If I use this syntax

```
<div data-bind="compose: composedView, activationData:'Here'"></div>
```

the view is loaded and the activate function of the viewModel is fired, but the activationData parameter is always undefined.

However! If I do this:

```
<div data-bind="compose: {model:composedView, activationData:'Here'}"></div>
```

then the activate function is fired and the activationData is populated properly. Any ideas why the activationData is not populated unless I specify the model object to bind?

The module that is being loaded by the compose binding is using a constructor and I have added the activate callback to the protoype like so:

```
ctor.prototype.activate = function (activationData) {

    var self = this;
    console.log(activationData);

}
```

Comment: Where have you seen that you can use it like this: `compose: composedView, activationData:'Here'`? Because the `activationData` is a property of the `compose` binding so it has to be set with `compose: {activationData:'Here'}` and in this case you need to set your model with `compose: {model:composedView, activationData:'Here'}`.

Comment: I don't think I have seen that specifically anywhere I just coded it up like that as there isn't a specific example in the docs that show the syntax like that. Lets see what happens when I do it that way.

Comment: Ok so when I do this `compose: composedView, {activationData:'Here'}` It loads the view and fires the activate function, but I am back to activationData being undefined.

Comment: It is only working with `compose: {model:composedView, activationData:'Here'}`. The compose binding either can take a "simple" value: string, property, etc. or a complex object where you can specify the additional properties for the binding like the `activationData`.

Comment: Ah, so if you want to use activationData you need to specify the object which means you have to declare either the model or the view? I think I understand now.

Comment: This question needs to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the activationData you must specify the model you are going to activate.